# CSS Menu not display sub UL in IE6

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble getting the following to display in ie6, everything works find in all browsers yet ie6 it seems to fall over on.

Instead of display:none ive also tried left:-9999999px yet it still doesnt seem to show/

http://jsfiddle.net/FVkzc/

Comment: Is it critical that an officially dead browser be supported?  I like [doing this](http://ie6update.com) on my sites.

Comment: If it's critical, I'd perhaps design a simple version of the entire site just for IE6.

Comment: I wish I could use the Kill IE6 banner! Too many idiots in our demographic using ie6 however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need [csshover.htc](http://www.google.com/search?q=csshover.htc) for IE6 to work properly.

Use it like so:

```
body { 
    behavior: url('csshover.htc');
}
```

The reason: IE6 doesn't do `hover` right on non-anchor elements.

Comment: If i was to add this to my IE6 stylesheet would I need to use @import?